# free or cheap open source browser-based Flash (flv) video players

Tags: flash, browser, asp.net-3.5, flvplayback, flash-video

Does any know of any free or cheap OSS browser based Flash video player?  It's going to be embedded on ASP.NET 3.5, a webcontrol would be handy, but not required.

I've been looking around and there are a lot of options.  My client wants to host a video on their web site like in a player like YouTube.

Here are some of the ones I've found but don't have time to vet:

- [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/)
- [coffeecup](http://www.coffeecup.com/video-player/)

Any help and additional options are GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used it in HTML directly, but I would recommend flowplayer. It all worked first time, supports youtube videos and I believe it is open source (though the current site didn't have the information about this in an obvious place).

Comment: by the way, love the flowplayer

Answer (score 0):

I've had wonderful success with the jwplayer.  It was extremely easy to set up, it's free for non-commercial use, and the commercial licenses were cheap.